# Trouble filtering data from Cratejoy API using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I was wondering if someone could help me filter data. I am trying to use the cratejoy api with google apps script to get data which I can then move to a google spreadsheet. I have never worked with APIs before, and it took quite a long time to get the authorization for the code to work. I am trying to use their filter features which can be found here: http://docs.cratejoy.com/docs/filtering-and-searching, so that I can get unshipped shipments after a certain date.  My authorization code looks like:

```
function myFunction() {

  var client_id = "********************";
  var client_secret = "*****************************";
  var encode = Utilities.base64Encode(client_id +  ':' + client_secret, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  var option = {
    headers : {
      Authorization: "Basic "+ encode,
    }
    };


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://api.cratejoy.com/v1/orders/?customer.name__like=%25%20Smith&placed_at__gt=2015-09-01T00:00:00Z', option);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

I have tried putting the filters in the headers like:

```
var option = {
    headers : {
      Authorization: "Basic "+ encode,
    }'
    status: 'unshipped'

    };
```

Then, I also tried editing the url like in the examples given on the website, but I keep getting a 400 error. Also, I noticed that I can only see ten results. Are there normally limits to how much data and can retrieve at a time? Do I have to keep making requests to get all the data?

Comment: I'd recommend first trying out the API outside of Apps Script. Perhaps on [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) so that you'd know exactly how the API behaves. Given that we have no authorisation to use the API, it just might be difficult for someone to share a solution before testing.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve my problem with Postman. It is a very useful application!